# How to access customer array by index in ajax request

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-promise

My functions looks as below:-

```
 function getCustomers() {
        var len = 5;
        var customers = new Array(len);
        var _promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

             var p = dataService.get(sData, 'Customer').then(function (data) {
                 if (data.entity === "Customer" && data.id > 0) {
                       //*******I am in need to access customers by index (i)**********;
                       //customers[i] = data.id
                       return alert("loop "+i); 
     //***** Issue-this alerts 5 times "loop 6" ***///////
                    }
             })

             _promises.push(p);
            }


        }

        $q.all(_promises).then(function () {

        })
    }
```

This is how Angular (dataService) looks like

```
 function read(data, entityName) {
        var url = "API_Url"
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
        .then(success)
        .catch(exception);

       function success(response){
       return response.data;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ES6 you can use `let` insted of `var` in the loop like this `for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {`

then with `let` you code will work, like this simple example

```
for (let i=0;i<5;i++){
 setTimeout(()=> console.log(i),0);
}
```

This is possible becouse of block scope nature of the `let` keyword

If not using ES6 you shoul make a copy of the i variable inside loop like this

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
 (function(j){
   setTimeout(()=> console.log(j),0)
 })(i);
}
```

You can find great explanation here https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure

Comment: Sorry!!I am not using ES6

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: Wow!! amazing keyword. I just replaced var with let & nothing else it is meeting my requirement. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kgn-web  I'm glad I can help, could you please mark my response as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Accepted, Please upvote my post if you find it worth